# std container for C-style array

Tags: c++, arrays, std

Is there an std container for C-style arrays with variable size?
For example, I have the following code

```
int size = 5;    // This is not a constant in general
int *my_array = SpecialAllocationFunction(size);
```

I want to be able to access this array with a C++, std-style container. Something that has iterators and functions like: `size`, `begin`, `end`, ...

I know that I can use `std::array` if `my_array` has a constant size. I also can write one myself, but I feel there bound to be something ready-made.

Comment: What about std::vector?

Comment: That definitely would be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). I seems strange that you know about `std::array` but not about the go-to standard container `std::vector`.

Comment: I thought `std::vector` would re-allocate the memory on the heap and copy my data to it.

Comment: And what do you think `SpecialAllocationFunction` would do? If it uses `new[]` then it would *also* allocate on the heap. Perhaps if you try to elaborate on the *actual* problem you have we might be able to help you better.

Comment: Ah, so you need a view over your "array"?

Comment: If you don't want a copy then `gls::span` should work.

Comment: When you say "C-style arrays", are you thinking of [VLAs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/1460794)?

Comment: Yes, a viewer over my own array. @Some programmer dude , I am trying to abstract my problem. My SpecialAllocationFunction allocates memory in a special memory buffer.

Comment: std::vector can be used with a special allocator

Comment: I appreciate that std::vector can be used with a special allocator. But that's not my use case here. I already have the pointer with an associated size. `gsl::span` seems to be what I need, although not sure if my compiler supports it. I am surprised that the C++ std doesn't have a solution.

Comment: Afaik, there is no such array view container. You could write one yourself, or just use pointers as iterators.

Comment: "I am surprised that the C++ std doesn't have a solution" - and I am still "surprised" that C++ doesn't have true multidimensional VLAs yet as C does since C99... There are some things, the C++ standard committee people don't seem to care about...

Comment: I was writing an answer and realized everything could be said as a comment: tldr: use `gsl::span` or write a trivial wrapper.

Comment: You don't need one, because standard algorithms (i.e. `std::sort` or `std::find` or whatever) should work fine with pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a custom allocator, it is possible to build a vector with a size known only at run time (so no `std::array` possible), wrapping an existing array. It is even possible to keep pre-existing values by overriding the special `construct` method<sup>(*)</sup>.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
/**
 * a pseudo allocator which receives in constructor an existing array
 *  of a known size, and will return it provided the required size
 *  is less than the declared one. If keep is true in contructor, 
 *  nothing is done at object construction time: original values are
 *  preserved
 * at deallocation time, nothing will happen
 */
template <class T>
class SpecialAllocator {
    T * addr;
    size_t sz;
    bool keep;
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    SpecialAllocator(T * addr, size_t sz, bool keep):
        addr(addr), sz(sz), keep(keep) {}
    size_t max_size() {
        return sz;
    }
    T* allocate(size_t n, const void* hint=0) {
        if (n > sz) throw std::bad_alloc();  // throws a bad_alloc... 
        return addr;
    }
    void deallocate(T* p, size_t n) {}
    template <class U, class... Args>
    void construct(U* p, Args&&... args) {
        if (! keep) {
            ::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
    template <class U>
    void destroy(U* p) {
        if (! keep) {
            p->~U();   // do not destroy what we have not constructed...
        }
    }

};
```

It can then be used that way:

```
int size = 5;    // This is not a constant in general
int *my_array = SpecialAllocationFunction(size);

SpecialAllocator<int> alloc(my_array, size);
std::vector<int, SpecialAllocator<int> > vec(size, alloc);
```

From that point, `vec` will be a true `std::vector` wrapping `my_array`.

Here is a simple code as demo:

```
int main(){
    int arr[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    SpecialAllocator<int> alloc(arr, 5, true); // original values will be preserved
    std::vector<int, SpecialAllocator<int> > vec(5, alloc);
    for(auto it= vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    try {
        vec.push_back(8);
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc& a) {
        std::cout << "allocation error" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will successfully output:

```
5 4 3 2 1 
allocation error
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> **BEWARE:** Construction/destruction may be involved in different places: `push_back`, `emplace_back`, etc. Really think twice about your real use case before using no-op `construct` and `destroy` methods.

Comment: If `arr` had values before creating `vec` (rather than assigning them afterwards), can I access them using `vec`?

Comment: @Tohiko: Not with my original code, because the `construct` method was not overriden. But just look at the edited one

Answer (score 3):

As @NathanOliver and @utnapistim said in the comments, `gsl::span` works. Since I don't want to include this library I ended up writing a "trivial wrapper" myself. Included below for others looking for an answer (and my future self)

```
template<class T>
class span {
public:
    inline span() : _data(0), _size(0) {}
    inline span(T* d, size_t s) : _data(d), _size(s) {}
    inline T& operator[](size_t index) { return _data[index]; }
    inline const T& operator[](size_t index) const { return _data[index];}
    inline size_t size() const { return _size; };
    inline T* begin() { return _data; }
    inline const T* begin() const { return _data; }

    inline T* end() { return _data+_size; }
    inline const T* end() const { return _data+_size; }
protected:
    T* _data;
    size_t _size;
};
```

Comment: `inline` is superfluous here.